# why do javascript libraries just link to text page when you attempt to DOWNLOAD them

Tags: javascript, download

I seem to be seeing many javascript libraries that, when you select their DOWNLOAD option, they actually direct me to an webpage with the js written as text.

I have to then copy/paste into my own text editor, and 'save as' any name I choose, meaning thousands of people are all carrying around the same library, but with potentially many many different file names.

As an example, look at the Raphaeljs: [raphael main page](http://raphaeljs.com/)

When you click its DOWNLOAD button, it directs me to [raphael js file](https://raw.github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/master/raphael-min.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Click on download button>> your file xyz.js will open in browser.

Press Ctrl + S to save page and select `*.*`(all file type)

that will automatically save file as .js

and >> save link as >> will also work with this. if you select file type.

Some old versions have default file type that will not automatically change the file type. so you may be having one of that. (I am not sure, just guessing)

I hope this will help

Comment: in a way this is not the answer ... I am really wanting to know WHY a website would present users with this awkward download scenario. 

... ... ... However, you have given a good explanation of HOW to do it (I did not know about the ctrl-S, myself). ... ... ... ... one caveat though: once downloaded (winXP), opening the .js file will trigger a warning ... None of my other .js files do this.

Comment: in Win XP if you were doing that using the Internet Explorer browser that might trigger this warning, as it was having security mechanism for that the js files, which were considered insecure, as part of malicious code were not identified in past and also Java/JavaScript was not fully supported by Microsoft in that era doe to some reasons. So to avoid that in WinXP you need to explitly set the security settings and disable warning messages for .js file.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on link -> Save Link as...

Comment: thanks for your response, but consider this: I do not want to save a "link" ... I want to save a "file"

Comment: and how does a person know that they must right-click in the first place? They can only come to know this by first realizing that normal click-behavior is not in effect, and thus maybe the person will think to look at the right-click possibilities.

Comment: also, on a WinXP, when I use this method, my file is saved as a .txt file, not a .js file ... this is the default behavior, and I cannot seem to override it via the SAVE AS dialog box .... thus I must manually change the name of the file once it is saved on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

right click and save link as is correct way, but u can use some tool,example firebug for firefox.
[nhac online](http://xapxinh.com)